# liquibase configuration with 2 master files - is it possible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I need to have specific migration to be run for some tests. So I would like to separate this test migration from other migrations. I was thinking to make second liquibase master file (test/resources/db/liquibase-master.xml) that includes first one + migration that i need only for tests. I'm not sure if this is even possible. Is this the right way to go, or is there another better way?

Comment: I never tried but the ```LiquibaseProperties``` bean has a ```changeLog``` attribute. So you should be able to set a master file in your defaut ```application.properties``` file and an other one in your ```application-test.properties``` file for the test profile

Comment: An other option is to have 1 unique master file that applies to all profiles and use the ```context``` attribute of a ```ChangeSet``` to set in which case the ```ChangeSet``` will be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below the way of achieving what you need with 1 single master file and using contexts. And the doc about it : https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html

Dev configuration : **src/main/config/application-dev.yml**

```
  liquibase:
    contexts: dev
```

Test configuration : **src/test/config/application.yml**

```
  liquibase:
    contexts: test
```

ChangeSet example : **ChangeSet_xxx_.xml**

```xml
<changeSet id="x1" context="dev">
 <!-- Executed in dev context only -->
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="x2" context="test">
 <!-- Executed in test context only -->
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="x3" context="test,dev">
 <!-- Executed in both contexts -->
</changeSet>
```